# Python how to sort values of pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I use the following python code

```py
param = bta.bt_get_used_param(all_trades_df)
for i in range(len(param)-1):
    g= lrun_trade_df.groupby([param[i],param[i+1]])['Profit'].sum().unstack(level=1) 
g
```

[image]

As you can see the P_0 dimension is not sorted as the lowest value, '8', appears as the last line.

Do you guys know what method I shall use to get both dimensions, P_0 and P_1, values sorted ?

Thks,

gfx

Comment: My guess, `param[i]` are strings. Try to convert to integers.

Comment: Indeed thks. I will fine tune but here below code provides evidence of type issue.
```lrun_trade_df['P_0'] = pd.Series(lrun_trade_df['P_0'],dtype='int64')```